# Trying to find my address on iancoleman.io

Tags: metamask

I didn't log my private key for my metamask wallet but have my secret phrase. After some searching I found online that I can visit iancoleman.io enter my phrase and when i locate my address, the private key will be listed. But I can't locate my address. I identified the right coin and am using bip 44 but i've looked through 10k addresses and haven't found mine. Is there a way to search by address?

Comment: take care where you enter your phrase, they can take your money

Answer (score 0):

You should never enter your seed phrase on a website. Whoever has your seed phrase has full access to your accounts.

Just use Metamask instead. Click on Import using account seed phrase. If you don't see your account after doing that, you have the wrong seed phrase and there is nothing you can do.

Comment: I have my seed phrase and opened my account. I just don't have my private key. So using my seed phrase just resets my metamask and there no money under the new address

Comment: Your seed phrase should not give you a new address in Metamask. It should give you the exact same address that you had before. If you have a new address, you are not using the right see phrase.